# Cannot select sink for Oracle linked service from data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a linked service that connects to an on-prem Oracle database through a self hosted integration runtime.

I am able to access this from a data factory pipeline - the dataset that uses the linked service is called pc_payinitil.

[image]

However, the pc_payinitial dataset is not available to select from the sink tab of a sink shape of a data flow:

[image]

Am I trying to do something that's not possible - or did I just go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the `Oracle` dataset is not supported in mapping data flow in the Azure data factory. It is only supported in copy activity source/sink and lookup activity.

There are only limited datasets that are supported in mapping data flow as of now. You can go through this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores) for more information on supported data stores in the Azure data factory.